# Foundation Range Slider with 2 Inputs?

Tags: slider, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to have 2 different inputs controlling a Foundation range slider? I need to add a field to set specific fractions (like so): https://codepen.io/jinch/pen/OaKpZX?editors=1000

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 columns">Width:</div>
  <div class="small-5 columns">
          <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="20" data-options="precision:3; decimal:3; start:8; end:36;" style="margin-top: 12px;">
            <span class="slider-handle slideWidth"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="customPort-2-width"></span>
              <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
          </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-5 columns">
    <input type="number" step="1" id="customPort-2-width" style="border: 1px solid #999999; display:inline-block; width:39%;">
    <select class="fractions fractionWidth" name="WidthFraction" style="border: 1px solid #999999; display:inline-block; width:39%;">
      <option value="0" selected="">0</option>
      <option value="1/8">1/8</option>
      <option value="1/4">1/4</option>
      <option value="3/8">3/8</option>
      <option value="1/2">1/2</option>
      <option value="5/8">5/8</option>
      <option value="3/4">3/4</option>
      <option value="7/8">7/8</option>
            </select>
    <span class="small">in.</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR The good news is this can be done! The bad news is that you'll need to adjust your code a bit. I'm typing this out at ten minutes past midnight so you will more than likely need to refactor this but I hope it's a starting point.

I'll go into the reasons for the implementation, but if you want to just get into it, I've created a Codepen https://codepen.io/jamie-endeavour/pen/zyxPaY?editors=1010

**A Bit of Background**

When I first found this question I looked at the Slider documentation and noticed a section about 'Reflow' - https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#reflow - after reading about this method I decided to look in the Foundation source code:

```
  _reflow() {
    this.setHandles();
  }
```

Then, I looked into `setHandles()`...

```
  setHandles() {
    if(this.handles[1]) {
      this._setHandlePos(this.$handle, this.inputs.eq(0).val(), true, () => {
        this._setHandlePos(this.$handle2, this.inputs.eq(1).val(), true);
      });
    } else {
      this._setHandlePos(this.$handle, this.inputs.eq(0).val(), true);
    }
  }
```

Notice here that `_setHandlePos()` makes a reference to a value from a property called `inputs`.

When the Slider class is initialized the following are set:

```
this.inputs = this.$element.find('input');

this.$input = this.inputs.length ? this.inputs.eq(0) : $(`#${this.$handle.attr('aria-controls')}`);
```

In your example, you weren't supplying an input element. So as you can see the code is using the value of `aria-controls` to build up the selector of the 'input'. This is where your restriction lies as you won't be able to associate two input fields with the Slider this way.

**The Solution**

So, remember the ternary that was used in `this.$input`? If we add an `<input>` within your `.slider` element, then we can use this as a reference point for the Slider.

```
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="20" data-options="precision:3; decimal:3; start:8; end:36;" style="margin-top: 12px;">
  <input type="hidden" id="slider-reference" value="8" />
  ...
```

Now that you have a reference that can be used between the two input fields. You can then update this reference field's value on the back of a change callback against each element, then Slider will read this and update accordingly.

The JS required for the `number` input is fairly straightforward as we are supplying the absolute number that Slider needs to calculate the width position.

The fraction input gets a bit funky because you need to return a fraction of the difference between your min and max value (28) rather than a fraction of your max value (36 in this case). This is why I've included additional calculations to ensure you get the correct position against the Slider element. This is also the part that I feel can be refactored with a fresh set of eyes

Finally, once you have acquired the new values in each change handler you simply call the `_reflow` method and this will update the Slider plugin accordingly without you having to re-initialize the plugin or anything nasty like that!

Comment: ~ Thank you for all the research and insight on this - Very helpful!!! I will dig into your code a bit to wrap my head around it. Ideally the slider will update the input fields and visa-versa so I will need to tweak slightly for functionality but this is definitely a step in the right direction! Cheers!

Comment: No worries at all! By all means, let me know if you have any questions. If the code has done the job then please can you accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply Jamie - distracted by the holiday crazy so haven't had much time to look over your code. I did notice on your codepen, the fraction input field is the only one that works with the slider. Is it possible to have both inputs work to control the slider and visa-versa? Meaning as you adjust the slider it will increase and decrease both the number and fraction values? Either way I appreciate what you have done regardless and can fiddle when I see a window. That may be next year at this rate : / ~ Good thing no urgent need ~ just figured I float the question out there. Thx.

Comment: Hey, @user7201898 no worries on the delayed reply I appreciate the time of the year! Yes it will be possible, I imagine you would need to write some code to update the values of the inputs on the back of the range input's change event. I didn't factor this in when writing the codepen - I thought you just wanted the range input to adjust when the number input and select box change. I would refer to the Slider's JS Events for this https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#js-events - hope this helps